# Images wont move based on changes with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I am expecting the images to shift to the right. Runner increments and prints 1px, 2px, 3px etc. to console, but new margin wont be set. What's the problem?

Together with the code below, what I have written above should be sufficient to understand my problem. But I am, at this point, simply writing to get rid of the prompt to write more text.

```
<body>
    <div class="normal">
        <img id="normal" src="whiteboard.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="scaled">
        <img id="scaled" src="whiteboard.jpeg">
    </div>
</body>
<style>
    .normal{
        background-image: url('whiteboard.jpeg');
        position:absolute;
        z-index:-1;
    }
    .scaled{
        transform:scale(120%);
        z-index:2;
        clip-path: circle(5% at 33% 42%);
    }

    .normal, .scaled{
        width:100vw;
        
    }

    div img{
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        
    }
</style>
<script>

    window.onload=function(){
        const normal = document.getElementById('normal');
        const scaled = document.getElementById('scaled');
        let runner =0;
        setInterval(function(){
            normal.style.marginRight="-"+runner+"px";
            scaled.style.marginRight="-"+runner+"px";
            runner++;
            console.log("respons - "+runner+"px")
        },50);
        
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `marginRight` style describes the distance of the `div` element to its parent's right side. A negative `marginRight` will not work here - instead try `marginLeft`. Depending your desired direction of the animation use a positive or negative value.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    const normal = document.getElementById('normal');
    const scaled = document.getElementById('scaled');
    let runner = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        normal.style.marginLeft = "-" +runner + "px";
        scaled.style.marginLeft = "-" +runner + "px";
        runner++;
        console.log("respons - "+runner+"px")
    }, 50);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="normal">
        <img id="normal" src="whiteboard.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="scaled">
        <img id="scaled" src="whiteboard.jpeg">
    </div>
</body>
<style>
    .normal {
        background-image: url('whiteboard.jpeg');
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .scaled{
        transform: scale(120%);
        z-index:2;
        clip-path: circle(5% at 33% 42%);
        background-color: red;
    }

    .normal, .scaled{
        width: 100vw;
        
    }

    div img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        
    }
</style>
```